# Role Based Login Authentication in IONIC

Tags: ionic2

How to do role based login in ionic app where my app currently will have two types of users , admin and user . When admin login it will direct to administrator page while when user login it will direct to normal user page .

Comment: after login, you will get a user type. according to user push or set root page. this.navctrl.root(user) / this.navctrl.root(admin)

Comment: Thanks manish kumar can you please explain more clearly the step . do i need to modify my database or just the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//I think you will get response after successful login, 
//In response you will also get userType which identify which type user. after that according to user setRoot page
//setRoot page for not showing login page on back

this.auth.validateUser().then((result) =>{
  if(result.status === 200){
    if(result.userType === "admin"){
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(adminPage);
    }
    if(result.userType === "user"){
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(userPage);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: thank you very much manish , appreciate your help . will try this way :)